# Unable to send test reports via email using maven plugin

Tags: selenium, maven, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, appium

I unable to send test reports via email using maven plugin.

Error: 1. [ERROR] Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465: AuthenticationFailedException -> [Help 1]

2. Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:995: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 995, response: -1 -> [Help 1]

I tried with port 465, 587 as well but nothing would work. Any suggestion would really help as well as not getting any solution over the internet yet

```
**Code:**
<plugin>
                <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>

                        <id>send a mail</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>

                        <configuration>
                            <!-- From Email address -->
                            <from>test@totalitycorp.com</from>

                            <!-- Email subject -->
                            <subject>Yovo Test Automation Report</subject>

                            <!-- Fail the build if the mail doesnt reach -->
                            <failonerror>false</failonerror>

                            <!-- host -->
                            <mailhost>smtp.gmail.com</mailhost>
                            <!-- port of the host -->
                            <mailport>995</mailport>
                            <mailssl>true</mailssl>
                            <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>                     

                            <!-- Email Authentication(USername and Password) -->
                            <mailuser>test@gmail.com</mailuser>
                            <mailpassword>234aASD</mailpassword>

                            <receivers>
                                <!-- To Email address -->
                                <receiver>abhi.c74@gmail.com</receiver>
                            </receivers>

                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <!-- Report directory Path -->
                                    <directory>/home/maverick/eclipse-workspace/YovoAndroidAutomation/test-output</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <!-- Report file name -->
                                        <include>emailable-report.html</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <!-- Use Regular Expressions like **/*.html if you want all the 
                                        html files to send -->
                                </fileSet>
                            </fileSets>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [ERROR] Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465: Authentication Required -> [Help 1]

This is very interesting issue. If we have to login in to Gmail from an external source—other than from the Gmail login—we need to enable the less secure option (i.e., set it to “ON”).

Here is how we do this:

- Go to the “Less secure apps” section in My Account.
- Next to “Access for less secure apps,” select "Turn on".

> ***Note to Google Apps users:*** This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.